# Auto connect mechanism in Bluetooth

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth

I was engaged in developing a Bluetooth Hardware device (loaded with HID profile) which pair, connect and interact with iOS and Android phone.Everything is fine. But my doubt is How to build Auto connection feature between them (BT device 2 Mobile). Do I need to build in  BT device Side or Mobile side? Who should initiate connection trigger?